# How to reuse existing docker container after rename the directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an existing docker container with the name `foo_db_1`.
The docker-compose file is located in the `foo` directory.
The container contains a huge DB.

I want to rename the directory from `foo` to `bar`

So I stopped the running container and renamed the directory and the container name

```
mv foo bar
docker rename foo_db_1 bar_db_1
```

Now when I try to start the container again I get a Conflict error:

```
docker-compose up -d
ERROR: for bar_db_1  Cannot create container for service db: Conflict. The container name "/bar_db_1" is already in use by container "4a9204e8031d72327be283967d2b9ec3268450140f00254eb2fc51ba8af0eb58". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

When I rename the container, then a completely new container is created and I have to import all DB data again to that container.
When I remove the container, then I will loose the DB data and also have to import all db data again.

When I run `docker inspect bar_db_1` I can see, that there are several entries pointing to the `foo` directory.

So how can I move an existing docker setup to another directory without loosing my existing data?

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"

volumes:
  db:

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'app'
      MYSQL_USER: 'dbuser'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '1234567890'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1234567890'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./db-dumps:/var/db-dumps
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: Can you change the `db` volume holding the actual database data to a bind-mounted host directory?  That would avoid this problem.  (There's no data in the container _per se_, but it is in a named volume which will have similar difficulties.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for you answer.  If I understand docker volumes correctly, then I already did that with using the named volume in the docker-compose.yml. This will create a volume on the host that can be referenced in multiple containers.

Comment: The `db` named volume is in Docker-controlled space, and it will be specific to a single Compose project by default.